# iOS Application crashes on WFConnector.framework method "getSensorConnections" in iPad retina only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, garmin

I have developed an iOS iPad application which works with "`ant + connectors (footpod and heartrate)`".

To interface with those two connectors I have used Wahoo api (`WFConnector.framework`). It was working fine till I tested it on iPad retina device.

It crashes on iPad 3 retina for method

```
- (NSArray*)getSensorConnections:(WFSensorType_t)sensorType;
```

when I try to connect garmin footpod with my application.

It is working fine with iPad 2 (ios7 and ios8) , I am not getting why it is crashing on iPad 3 retina only. I think it might be because of 64 bit architecture in iPad 3. But what can be the relation of it with crash.

I have used following code to update sensor:

```
- (void)updateSensorStatusNew
{

    @try {

        @autoreleasepool {
            // configure the status fields for the heartrate sensor.
            NSArray* connections = [hardwareConnector getSensorConnections:WF_SENSORTYPE_HEARTRATE]; /////////**************************** I GET CRASH ON THIS LINE
            ALog(@"here in %@",[self class]);
            WFSensorConnection* sensor = ([connections count]>0) ? (WFSensorConnection*)[connections objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
            if ( sensor )
            {
                //WFHeartrateData* hrData = [(WFHeartrateConnection*)sensor  getHeartrateData];
                BOOL hrConnected = (sensor != nil && sensor.isConnected) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                //USHORT devId = sensor.deviceNumber;
                if  ( hrConnected) {
                    //lbl2.text = @"HR 7 Connected";
                }
                else {
                    // lbl2.text = @"HR 8 Not Connected";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //lbl2.text = @"HR 9 Not Connected";
            }

            // configure the status fields for the Bike Speed and Cadence sensor.
            connections = [hardwareConnector getSensorConnections:WF_SENSORTYPE_FOOTPOD];
            ALog(@"%@,%lu",connections,(unsigned long)connections.count);
            ALog(@"here in %@",[self class]);
            sensor = ([connections count]>0) ? (WFSensorConnection*)[connections objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
            ALog(@"here in %@",[self class]);
            if ( sensor )
            {
                //WFFootpodData* fpData = [(WFFootpodConnection*)sensor  getFootpodData];
                ALog(@"here in 308 %@",[self class]);
                BOOL fpConnected = (sensor != nil && sensor.isConnected) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                //USHORT devId = sensor.deviceNumber;
                if  ( fpConnected) {
                    // lbl3.text = @"FP 10 Connected";
                }
                else {
                    //lbl3.text = @"FP 11 Not Connected";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //lbl3.text = @"FP 12 Not Connected";
                /*
                 fpConnectedLabel.text = @"No";
                 fpDeviceIdLabel.text = @"n/a";
                 fpSignalLabel.text = @"n/a";*/
            }
        }
        ALog(@"here in 327 %@",[self class]);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception);
    }
    @finally {
        //Display Alternative
    }

}
```

And the crash log I am getting on that function is

```
Nov 14 11:26:52  VirtualRunner-V3[6642] <Warning>: App crashing with exception: *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
Nov 14 11:26:52  VirtualRunner-V3[6642] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
        *** First throw call stack:
        (0x2ffeaf83 0x3ab8dccf 0x2ff21a39 0x8448b 0x839cf 0x2ffad1a1 0x2ff214ef 0x3090ca3d 0x3091131b 0x27c3f 0x2d00d1 0x309d5b05 0x2ffb6167 0x2ffb5d7f 0x2ffb411b 0x2ff1eebf 0x2ff1eca3 0x34e45663 0x3286b14d 0x172e29 0x22108)
Nov 14 11:26:52  VirtualRunner-V3[6642] <Warning>: We received a signal: 6
```

I  have also updated my `WFConnector.framework` to the latest version.

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try NSLog connections object, immediately after its initialization.

Comment: I have tried it , it contains one object of "footpod" if foot pod is connected with iPad.